# Send file content with Php (net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH)

Tags: php, http-headers

I would like to know how can I send a mpeg file content to a client browser.

I have this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("13662f12.mp3"));
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
readfile("13662f12.mp3");
```

On local it works fine. but on server the file stops reading after 10 seconds. I downloaded the song with ctrl+s and play it with a player without any problem.

I have this error: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH on Chrome.

I tried on Firefox too but nothing.

I would like to know why too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. The issue is related with server settings. 
Maybe there's a execution time limit set on the server. Disable it with `set_time_limit(0);` (if it's allowed).

Also, try to figure out what causes the issue. Try to send smaller files and check if they are sent correctly. Inspect the headers that the server sends.

Comment: Thanks, The server max_execution_time is 20. I will try premium to see if I can change it. Because set_time_limit is block on free.